# AUTO_INCREMENT in CREATE TABLE Throwing JDBC.SQLSERVEREXCEPTION

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to create a AUTO_INCREMENT field in my SQL table that is being created through a SQL Statement.execute, but it keep on throwing a `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'`.

Here is my code for creating my table:

```
public class CreateTable {
Connection con;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet queryResults = null;

public CreateTable() {

    con = DatabaseUtil.getConnection();

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        stmt.execute("IF OBJECT_ID('A00776920_Members') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE A00776920_Members");

        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE A00776920_Members ("
                + "memberid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
                + "firstName VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL, "
                + "lastName VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL, "
                + "address VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL, "
                + "city VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL, "
                + "code CHAR(7) DEFAULT NULL, "
                + "country VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL, "
                + "phoneNumber CHAR(14) DEFAULT NULL, "
                + "email VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL, "
                + "PRIMARY KEY (memberid))";
        stmt.execute(createTable);

        stmt.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CreateTable();
}
```

}

The exact error that is being thrown at me is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at a00776920.assignment.dao.CreateTable.<init>(CreateTable.java:40)
at a00776920.assignment.dao.CreateTable.main(CreateTable.java:53)
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using wrong JDBC driver.  The `create table` syntax is clearly MySQL, but you are obviously using MS SQL Server JDBC Driver.  Use the right driver - and you should be fine.

You can download MySQL JDBC drivers from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.5.html

Comment: I added the jar file to my project, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It's not just the JAR file - somewhere in your code you must be loading the driver with `Class.forName` or similar - make sure you are loading the correct driver: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`